# launch intellij using $EDITOR from commandline, interactively, without incurring the startup/plugin penalty

Tags: git, intellij-idea, mercurial

I want to launch intellij from the commandline interactively, meaning that the intellij process ends after it is invoked. My goal is to use intellij as the $EDITOR environment variable in bash. There are many usages for this, editing commit messages being one of them. I require that:

1. it must not take a long time. I want to launch it quickly, make changes and close the window.
2. it must be launched interactively so that I can use the editor to change my commit messages in mercurial or git, for example. If the process closes too soon, git and mercurial assumes that I'm done editing the file and no changes are saved.

## An explicit example to reproduce my issue

The first step is to lauch intellij; this takes a long time because it loads plugins and shows a splash screen with progress.

I make changes to code, and afterward I use an $EDITOR  in bash, invoking mercurial with `--edit`, which will open an editor of my choice, allowing me to change my commit messages in my mercurial changeset.

```
user@host:/hg/repo$ HGEDITOR=/opt/idea-$ideaversion/bin/idea.sh hg qrefresh --edit
```

My issue I'm having is that this is printed instead of editing the file

```
Already running
```

Comment: Git and Mercurial are processes which exist outside of IntelliJ AFAIK.  Can you add a description about why you think you need to do this?

Comment: Adding to the preceeding comment: what problem do you try to solve? Figuratively you seem to ask in how to use a fork when you actually should want to ask how to eat a chicken

Comment: what part of "so that i can use the editor to change my commit messages" is confusing to you guys?

Comment: There is no such way. The intended way to use IntelliJ IDEA for editing commit messages is to use the built-in Commit Changes dialog.

Comment: thanks @yole how are you certain there is no way?

Comment: Adding to @TimBiegeleisen's comment, just use the command-line tool for the corresponding RCS instead. For the most part you can do more from the command line, not less.

Comment: The point of the question is to add to our understanding of using intellij in an interesting and useful way; being perfectly capable of using the commandline does not fill in this gap.

Comment: there are many other usages than editing commit messages. maybe i should edit the question to say, "how can I set my commandline EDITOR environment variable to intellij?"

Comment: @activedecay from having spent many years working on IntelliJ IDEA and IntelliJ Platform-based IDEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no such way. The intended way to use IntelliJ IDEA for
>   editing commit messages is to use the built-in Commit Changes dialog.
>   [I know this] from having spent many years working on IntelliJ IDEA
>   and IntelliJ Platform-based IDEs

– yole